# Delete Accepted answer, where the consensus is that the answer is wrong

Tags: support, delete

https://superuser.com/a/1685364/603073

The consensus is that the answer I provided is wrong, which on reflection I now agree with. However, I can't delete my answer as it has been accepted.

Is there a process to un-accept the answer/a mod to remove the flag, which will then allow me to delete it?

Note - I am aware I will lose the rep.

Answer (score 3):

Well in general - the reasoning is that it could be useful for others (and as a wrong answer it isn't), and OP spent the effort creating an answer.

Considering the circumstances, (and that I was in a similar pickle over an obviously wrong answer to an issue I had recently!) deleting the answer *does* seem like the right thing to do.

We've deleted the answer for you, since we can't unaccept an answer on OP's behalf.